# Adding configurations to manually created startup.cs class in asp.net web API project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, startup, .net-framework-version

I am new to asp.net and started with a web API project in Visual Studio. I would like to use these web APIs for an Angular app. For that I will have to enable CORS and configure SignalR

> In the ConfigureServices method, we are adding SignalR to the IService collection. And in a Configure
> method, we are adding SignalR to the request pipeline by pointing to our ChartHub with the provided /chart path.

(Reference: https://code-maze.com/netcore-signalr-angular/)

I don't have a `Startup.cs` file in my web API project, so I have added an `OWIN startup class`. This class has a `Configuration` method but not `ConfigureService` or `Configure`. I am confused on how to add enable CORS and SignalR in `startup.cs`. How to add these configurations in startup.cs class?

Comment: It sounds like you've not started with the correct project type.  Are you sure it's a .net core API project you chose?

Comment: I do not want a .net core project. I created a asp.net web application(.NET Framework)

Comment: .NET Framework projects don't have a startup.cs, and the reference you post is for .net core.

Comment: Okay. If .NET Framework projects don't have a startup.cs, where should be the configurations like CORS be added?

Comment: The answer posted is probably your best bet, but TBH, when .net 5 comes around (very soon), I think you won't have much choice.  .NET core is the future, so you should start any new projects as core and convert old ones as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Startup class in root of your project and marked it with OwinStartup attribute to indicate the class to be used for automatic setup.

Then you need to implement Configuration method where you can setup things like authentication, CORs, Signalr and many more.

You also can add Owin Startup Class via Add Item in Visual Studio. It will add basic setup to config for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection#create-an-aspnet-web-app-using-owin-startup

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Example.Web.Startup))]
namespace Example.Web
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private static CorsOptions _corsOptions = new CorsOptions
        {
            PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
            {
                PolicyResolver = context =>
                {
                    var policy = new CorsPolicy();
                    foreach (string domain in ConfigHelper.AllowedCorsDomains.Split(','))
                    {
                        policy.Origins.Add(domain);
                    }

                    policy.AllowAnyMethod = true;
                    policy.AllowAnyHeader = true;
                    policy.SupportsCredentials = true;
                    return Task.FromResult(policy);
                }
            }
        };

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(_corsOptions);
            app.MapSignalR();

            AccessTokenFormat = new SecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>(new TicketSerializer(), app.GetDataProtectionProvider().Create("ASP.Net Identity"), new Base64TextEncoder());

            
            OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                AccessTokenFormat = AccessTokenFormat
            };

            if (provider != null)
            {
                OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions.Provider = provider;
            }

            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error `ConfigHelper` doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: Well ConfigHelper used to get configuration from web.config. For this specific place it is getting comma separated list of domains for which to enable cors. If you don’t want to store your domains in web.config you can just replace the line with ConfigHelper to “yourdomain1,yourdomain2” string